# I need help identifying a problem which causes console debug spam in Anylogic PLE using RL4J on Mac

Tags: java, anylogic, dl4j

I am using RL4J in the newest version of Anylogic PLE on a Mac to train a reinforcement learning agent. I created the jar for the RL4J-core Version 1.0.0-beta7 using Maven in IntelliJ and added it to Anylogic.

As soon as I execute my model the console starts getting flooded by debug notifications and this doesn't stop until I end the execution. The displayed messages seem to always repeat in a patter with minor differences if any at all.

This is very annoying as I am unable to view the output or error messages printed to the console. I did a lot of research, but was unable to narrow the problem down as I am neither an expert in Anylogic nor in Java. Other models without the RL4J jar run perfectly fine in Anylogic.

I tried using different versions of RL4J, but the problem kept occurring.

The first lines which are printed to the console after the start look as following:

```
15:33:09.395 [main] INFO spark.staticfiles.StaticFilesConfiguration - StaticResourceHandler configured with folder = /standalone
15:33:09.405 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: before, +/*paths, spark.FilterImpl$1@20140db9
15:33:09.405 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: get, /three, spark.RouteImpl$1@738dc9b
15:33:09.406 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: get, /tiles/:tileProvider/:x/:y/:z, spark.RouteImpl$1@d86a6f
15:33:09.406 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: get, /:uuid/frames, spark.RouteImpl$1@5ab956d7
15:33:09.407 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: get, /:uuid/configuration, spark.RouteImpl$1@750e2b97
15:33:09.408 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: get, /:uuid/resources, spark.RouteImpl$1@740cae06
15:33:09.409 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: get, /:uuid/internal-resources, spark.RouteImpl$1@f78a47e
15:33:09.410 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: post, /:uuid/stop, spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1@1530c739
15:33:09.411 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: post, /:uuid/action, spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1@78e4deb0
15:33:09.411 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: post, /:uuid/file, spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1@7d0b7e3c
15:33:09.411 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: post, /:uuid/snapshot, spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1@4b741d6d
15:33:09.412 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: post, /:uuid/command, spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1@8f2ef19
15:33:09.412 [main] DEBUG spark.route.Routes - Adds route: post, /:uuid/max-fps, spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1@2cf3d63b
15:33:09.412 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging to Logger[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] via org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
15:33:09.435 [Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @839ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
15:33:09.709 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle - org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@c2d3c5f[9.4.8.v20171121] added {QueuedThreadPool@qtp845981693{STOPPED,8<=0<=200,i=0,q=0},AUTO}
15:33:09.725 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle - HttpConnectionFactory@d6013cd[HTTP/1.1] added {HttpConfiguration@36c43df{32768/8192,8192/8192,https://:0,[ForwardedRequestCustomizer@2f0ab8cc]},POJO}
15:33:09.734 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@1fe67be4{null,[]}{0.0.0.0:0} added {org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@c2d3c5f[9.4.8.v20171121],UNMANAGED}
15:33:09.735 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@1fe67be4{null,[]}{0.0.0.0:0} added {QueuedThreadPool@qtp845981693{STOPPED,8<=0<=200,i=0,q=0},AUTO}
15:33:09.735 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@1fe67be4{null,[]}{0.0.0.0:0} added {org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@c6154e8,AUTO}
15:33:09.735 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@1fe67be4{null,[]}{0.0.0.0:0} added {org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@3606d473,POJO}
15:33:09.736 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle - ServerConnector@1fe67be4{null,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:0} added {HttpConnectionFactory@d6013cd[HTTP/1.1],AUTO}
15:33:09.736 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - ServerConnector@1fe67be4{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:0} added HttpConnectionFactory@d6013cd[HTTP/1.1]
```

An exert from the ever repeating part looks like this:

```
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137} onContentComplete
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137} onRequestComplete
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput - HttpInputOverHTTP@4b397b17[c=0,q=0,[0]=null,s=STREAM] addContent EOF
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137}<-SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=1/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137} parsed true HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1}
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - releaseRequestBuffer HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137}<-SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=1/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137}
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137} handle //localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137 
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - handling HttpChannelState@113d929a{s=IDLE a=NOT_ASYNC i=true r=IDLE w=false}
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137} action DISPATCH
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST GET /uuid/frames on HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137}
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - sessionHandler=com.anylogic.engine.internal.u.d$12013616133==dftMaxIdleSec=-1
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - session=null
15:59:35.537 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.QoSFilter - Accepted Request(GET //localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137)@3da2da7e
15:59:35.538 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG spark.Request - matchedPart: :uuid = uuid
15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - sendResponse info=null content=DirectByteBuffer@a974d35[p=0,l=11992,c=32768,r=11992]={<<<\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xEc=\rs\xE26\xD3...+U{lC\x0e\x14\xE0K\xFf\x1f\x00\x00\xFf\xFf>>>\xB4\xD5\x97n+\tt,\xC0\x01\xE2 }\xCe\x93O\xD0...@j1GTn\x84?<\xD2K\x1d\x85\xD7\xF1} complete=false committing=true callback=Blocker@20d33a7{null}
15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - COMMIT for /uuid/frames on HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=true,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137}
200 null HTTP/1.1
Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2020 14:59:35 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8


15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback@2ec1132[PROCESSING][i=HTTP/1.1{s=200,h=4,cl=-1},cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$CommitCallback@1e767625] generate: NEED_HEADER (null,[p=0,l=11992,c=32768,r=11992],false)@START
15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator - generateHeaders HTTP/1.1{s=200,h=4,cl=-1} last=false content=DirectByteBuffer@a974d35[p=0,l=11992,c=32768,r=11992]={<<<\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xEc=\rs\xE26\xD3...+U{lC\x0e\x14\xE0K\xFf\x1f\x00\x00\xFf\xFf>>>\xB4\xD5\x97n+\tt,\xC0\x01\xE2 }\xCe\x93O\xD0...@j1GTn\x84?<\xD2K\x1d\x85\xD7\xF1}
15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator - Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2020 14:59:35 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8


15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator - CHUNKED_CONTENT
15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback@2ec1132[PROCESSING][i=HTTP/1.1{s=200,h=4,cl=-1},cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$CommitCallback@1e767625] generate: FLUSH ([p=0,l=210,c=8192,r=210],[p=0,l=11992,c=32768,r=11992],false)@COMMITTED
15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - write: WriteFlusher@78500b69{IDLE}->null [HeapByteBuffer@7fd3c356[p=0,l=210,c=8192,r=210]={<<<HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n...1121)\r\n\r\n2ED8\r\n>>>) Chrome/87.0.427...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00},DirectByteBuffer@a974d35[p=0,l=11992,c=32768,r=11992]={<<<\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xEc=\rs\xE26\xD3...+U{lC\x0e\x14\xE0K\xFf\x1f\x00\x00\xFf\xFf>>>\xB4\xD5\x97n+\tt,\xC0\x01\xE2 }\xCe\x93O\xD0...@j1GTn\x84?<\xD2K\x1d\x85\xD7\xF1}]
15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - update WriteFlusher@78500b69{WRITING}->null:IDLE-->WRITING
15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint - flushed 12202 SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=W,to=4/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=COMMITTED}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=true,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137}
15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - Flushed=true 210/210+1 WriteFlusher@78500b69{WRITING}->null
15:59:35.540 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - update WriteFlusher@78500b69{IDLE}->null:WRITING-->IDLE
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback@2ec1132[PROCESSING][i=HTTP/1.1{s=200,h=4,cl=-1},cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$CommitCallback@1e767625] generate: DONE ([p=210,l=210,c=8192,r=0],[p=11992,l=11992,c=32768,r=0],false)@COMMITTED
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - sendResponse info=null content=DirectByteBuffer@a974d35[p=0,l=10,c=32768,r=10]={<<<\x03\x00\xC3\x9d\x0c\xEd\x95\xF9\x01\x00>>>\xEc=\rs\xE26\xD3Es\xD3y\xDe\xBb\x96\x0f...@j1GTn\x84?<\xD2K\x1d\x85\xD7\xF1} complete=true committing=false callback=Blocker@20d33a7{null}
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback@2ec1132[PROCESSING][i=null,cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$ContentCallback@5a4bba67] generate: NEED_CHUNK (null,[p=0,l=10,c=32768,r=10],true)@COMMITTED
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback@2ec1132[PROCESSING][i=null,cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$ContentCallback@5a4bba67] generate: FLUSH (null,[p=0,l=10,c=32768,r=10],true)@COMPLETING
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - write: WriteFlusher@78500b69{IDLE}->null [HeapByteBuffer@4f4fa906[p=0,l=5,c=1024,r=5]={<<<\r\nA\r\n>>>\r\n\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00},DirectByteBuffer@a974d35[p=0,l=10,c=32768,r=10]={<<<\x03\x00\xC3\x9d\x0c\xEd\x95\xF9\x01\x00>>>\xEc=\rs\xE26\xD3Es\xD3y\xDe\xBb\x96\x0f...@j1GTn\x84?<\xD2K\x1d\x85\xD7\xF1}]
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - update WriteFlusher@78500b69{WRITING}->null:IDLE-->WRITING
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint - flushed 15 SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=W,to=1/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=COMPLETING}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=true,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137}
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - Flushed=true 5/5+1 WriteFlusher@78500b69{WRITING}->null
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - update WriteFlusher@78500b69{IDLE}->null:WRITING-->IDLE
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback@2ec1132[PROCESSING][i=null,cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$ContentCallback@5a4bba67] generate: FLUSH (null,[p=10,l=10,c=32768,r=0],true)@COMPLETING
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - write: WriteFlusher@78500b69{IDLE}->null [HeapByteBuffer@4f4fa906[p=0,l=7,c=1024,r=7]={<<<\r\n0\r\n\r\n>>>\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}]
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - update WriteFlusher@78500b69{WRITING}->null:IDLE-->WRITING
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint - flushed 7 SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=W,to=0/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=COMPLETING}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=true,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137}
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - Flushed=true 7/7+0 WriteFlusher@78500b69{WRITING}->null
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher - update WriteFlusher@78500b69{IDLE}->null:WRITING-->IDLE
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback@2ec1132[PROCESSING][i=null,cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$ContentCallback@5a4bba67] generate: DONE (null,[p=10,l=10,c=32768,r=0],true)@END
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - FinalSession=null old_session_manager=null this=com.anylogic.engine.internal.u.d$12013616133==dftMaxIdleSec=-1
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - handled=true async=false committed=true on HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=true,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137}
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - unhandle HttpChannelState@113d929a{s=DISPATCHED a=NOT_ASYNC i=true r=IDLE w=false}
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=true,a=COMPLETING,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/frames?fullFrame=false&time=7868.795000002137} action COMPLETE
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - onComplete HttpChannelState@113d929a{s=COMPLETING a=NOT_ASYNC i=false r=IDLE w=false}
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - COMPLETE for /uuid/frames written=12002
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - recycle HttpChannelState@113d929a{s=COMPLETED a=NOT_ASYNC i=false r=IDLE w=false}
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - reset HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1}
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - END --> START
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null} handle exit, result COMPLETE
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint - filled 0 SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint - filled 0 SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}
15:59:35.541 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}<-SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null} filled 0 HeapByteBuffer@7fd3c356[p=0,l=0,c=8192,r=0]={<<<>>>HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - action=null wakeup=false
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint - Key interests updated 1 -> 0 on SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=74/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-31] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@6d6986ac waiting on select
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint - filled 486 SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=74/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}<-SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null} filled 486 HeapByteBuffer@7fd3c356[p=0,l=486,c=8192,r=486]={<<<POST /uuid/comman....9,en;q=0.8\r\n\r\n>>>q=0.9,en;q=0.8\r\n\r...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection - HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}<-SocketChannelEndPoint@34e6b010{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56523<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:20871,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/3600000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@70e84137[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@2e54e922{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=20,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null} parse HeapByteBuffer@7fd3c356[p=0,l=486,c=8192,r=486]={<<<POST /uuid/comman....9,en;q=0.8\r\n\r\n>>>q=0.9,en;q=0.8\r\n\r...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} {}
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - parseNext s=START HeapByteBuffer@7fd3c356[p=0,l=486,c=8192,r=486]={<<<POST /uuid/comman....9,en;q=0.8\r\n\r\n>>>q=0.9,en;q=0.8\r\n\r...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - START --> SPACE1
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - SPACE1 --> URI
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - URI --> SPACE2
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - SPACE2 --> REQUEST_VERSION
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - REQUEST_VERSION --> HEADER
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Host: localhost:20871 --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Host: localhost:20871 --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Connection: keep-alive --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Connection: keep-alive --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Content-Length: 0 --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Content-Length: 0 --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4278.0 Safari/537.36 --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4278.0 Safari/537.36 --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Accept: */* --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Accept: */* --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> IN_NAME
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> IN_NAME
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> IN_NAME
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:null --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8 --> IN_VALUE
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER:Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8 --> FIELD
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HEADER --> END
15:59:35.616 [qtp1324110161-27] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - REQUEST for //localhost:20871/uuid/command?cmd=close&parameters= on HttpChannelOverHttp@3c2f80e4{r=21,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=//localhost:20871/uuid/command?cmd=close&parameters=}
POST //localhost:20871/uuid/command?cmd=close&parameters= HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:20871
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4278.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:20871
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:20871/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

I don't know if it is important but the pom.xml I used to create the jar looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>rl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>rl4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

It would be great of any of you knew what could cause such a problem. If you need any further details please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you don't have a file like this that enables debug messages in your JAR: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/resources/logback.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

Create a file called "logback.xml" on your project folder
This file should look like this with nothing in it:

```
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

Now go to the simulation experiment properties, on the advanced section under "Java machine arguments" write this:

```
-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml
```

additionally, you can watch this video i made on how to create the jar file to use DL4J if you have doubts on how you did it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaCa5F_PaHk